# How to make the right-most frame in a QHBoxLayout the widest

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4

I am having trouble with sizing, in particular, I would like the left most element to stay relatively fixed in size while having the right most expand. How would this be controlled? I tried to use various combinations of the size policies, but that didnt quite seem to work. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a combination of [`QWidget::setFixedWidth`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFixedWidth) and [`QBoxLayout::setStretchFactor`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#setStretchFactor):

Setting a layout item to have a `stretchFactor` of `0` tells the layout to allocate only the minimum required space to that item (a dimension which you can specify if needed with `QWidget::setFixedWidth`) - anything larger causes the layout to allocate space proportionally.

e.g. Three `QWidget`s with `stretchFactor`s of `0`, `1` and `2` respectively will cause the minimum possible space to be given to the first `QWidget`with the remaining space divided among the last two `QWidget`s at a ratio of 2:1.

Also bear in mind that `stretchFactor` can be set when you [add an item to a layout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#addWidget).

Comment: What do you mean by dockables? (`QDockWidget`s?) - can you post some example code so we can see what's going on?